# How to convert hex to wasm and abi

Tags: abi, wasm

I have an old, previously deployed smart contract and I want to get its abi and wasm. How can I do that from hex data that i found on eos chain explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the wasm and abi with `cleos` using:

`cleos get code ACCOUNT_NAME`

and

`cleos get abi ACCOUNT_NAME`

Comment: The problem is that I want to get previous ABI and Code. `cleos get code` and `cleos get abi` would return me current ABI and Code